# External display does not wake from sleep unless laptop lid is opened

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, external-display

OS: Windows 10

Laptop: Acer Swift SF314-53G

Monitor: ASUS VP249QGR

Connected via HDMI.

When the lid is closed while coming back from sleep, the monitor says no HDMI signal, even though the mouse and other components are working just fine.

Opening and then closing the lid fixes this problem, but that is difficult to do every time.

Comment: Set your lid (power functions) to sleep (suspend) when lid is closed.  Then you do need to open the lid to un-suspend and that should solve your issue.

Comment: I too have this problem on one laptop (HP) and not another (Dell) regardless of my power function settings.  I can only assume that it has to do with a different ACPI implementation.  I know this doesn't really help you but I wanted you to know that you aren't alone.